# How to export dataframe to html with utf8 encoding

Tags: r, r2html

I'm using R2HTML package to export a dataframe to html, using example code below:

```
library(R2HTML)

HTML(dataframe_name, 
     Border = 0,
     align = "center",
     classfirstline = "firstline",
     classcellinside = "cellinside",
     row.names = FALSE,
     append = TRUE)
```

The store column though isn't displaying some of the characters correctly

Dataframe in R:

```
 store          store_spend
 H.Králové      10,000
```

Dataframe in HTML:

```
 store          store_spend
 H.KrÃ¡lovÃ©    10,000
```

Is there a way to keep the utf8 encoding whilst transferring it to html?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not an R2HTML issue, but the default HTML page encoding: that is, R2HTML is creating the HTML file properly, but it is not correctly rendered in your web browser.

You need to insert something like `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the HTML code, e.g., using `HTML("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">", file)` in your R code.

For instance:

```
library(R2HTML)
dir.create(file.path(tempdir(),"R2HTML"))
target <- HTMLInitFile(file.path(tempdir(),"R2HTML"),filename="sample", 
                       BackGroundColor="#BBBBEE")
HTML("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">", file = target)
HTML(dataframe_name, 
     Border = 0,
     align = "center",
     classfirstline = "firstline",
     classcellinside = "cellinside",
     row.names = FALSE,
     append = TRUE)
```

I hope it helps.